# Can we drop and recreate primary key in SQL Server table @ Production environment? Do we have to down the server for it or we can do it live?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Can we drop and recreate a composite primary key in a SQL Server table in production environment? Do we have take down the server for it, or can we do it live?

Because we have to add more columns to the primary key. If we done it in live what are the problems we have to face?

Comment: more articles are there on this topic.Why can't you google it

Comment: That of course will make queries slow when the index is missing + someone could create a row that violates it -- is this a problem for you or not, that we can't really answer, and you didn't even mention how big is the table.

Comment: Haven't really checked what create ... with (drop_existing = on) does under the hood, maybe that helps

Comment: table is having 500+ million records

Answer (score 3):

You can remove primary key from table.This will also remove clustered index of that table if you have't mentioned explicitly on other column.

To remove primary key run below query

```
-- Drop CHECK CONSTRAINT from the table
     ALTER TABLE /*schema*/./*table*/
        DROP CONSTRAINT /*constraint_name*/
     GO
```

and to add primary key run below code

```
-- Add a new CHECK CONSTRAINT to the table
ALTER TABLE /*schema*/./*table*/
    ADD CONSTRAINT /*contraint_name*/ /*constraint_type*/ (/*constraint_column_name*/ /*logical_expression*/)
GO
```

Comment: we can do it..but my concern is it have to be done on production environment. so is there any impacts for another operations which are in live?

Comment: I ran a quick test where I opened a transaction, selected all rows from the table then sleep for 10s, ran the drop and create constraint statements, then selected again and slept for 10s, then rolled back the transaction. There was no block and the select code was unaffected. I then tried doing `SELECT * FROM ... WITH(XLOCK)` instead and the alter scripts waited a full 20 seconds before they ran (i.e. they were indeed blocked on the lock I explicitly opened). Note I did not test any write cases.